# Cannot find name 'Diagnostics'

Tags: typescript

I've cloned the Typescript repo and am looking at the code, but it is full of this error:

> Cannot find name 'Diagnostics'

on lines that look like this:

```
Diagnostics._0_expected
```

I can see a JSON file in the same folder, with a list of diagnostic messages, but how do I generate this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should build the library first.
Please refer to the [building](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript#building) section in the readme file of your specific version (The build system used to be jake and now it is gulp).
All you need to do is:

1. Install the build system globaly (jake/gulp)
2. Run npm install
3. Run jake local **or** gulp local (according to the build system).

[building section of 1.7](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/release-1.7)
[building section of 1.8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/release-1.8)
[Latest](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript#building)